# Ajuda com JQuery $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Meu arquivo .js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#uf").on("change", function () {
    atualizaProfissional();
});

$("#botao").on("click", function(){
    s = $("#municipio").val();
    if (s == 1){
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://drglass.com.br/uf/popup1.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Uhul! Nós atendemos sua região. Temos uma unidade de atendimento pertinho de você. Ligue agora mesmo e faça um orçamento.');
    }else{
        $("#imagem").attr("src","https://drglass.com.br/uf/popup0.png");
        $("#mensagem").html('Ops! Ainda não estamos na sua cidade. Mas muito em breve levaremos a melhor empresa de Vidros para sua região, consulte nosso plano de expansão.');
    }
});

function atualizaProfissional() {
    var options = {};
    options.url = "https://drglass.com.br/uf/listaCidades.php";
    options.type = "POST";
    options.data = { "uf": $("#uf").val() };
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.success = function (data) {
        $('#municipio').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("#municipio").append("<option value='" + data[i].atende + "'>" + data[i].Nome + "</option>");
        }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
});
```

Como estou chamando:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://drglass.com.br/uf/municipios.js"></script>
```

Link do erro:

```
https://drglass.com.br/regioes/
```

Não tenho mais ideia de como resolver. Na minha máquina local, funciona de boa, quando faço o upload dá esse erro.

Comment: Veja esse artigo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343714/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-calling-jquery-function. O Wordpress já injeta um JQuery. Você está tentando reinserir a biblioteca. Veja como fazer aqui: https://pt.blogpascher.com/wordpress-tutorial/como-add-corretamente-the-code-jquery-on-wordpress

Comment: Uma pessoa postou a solução aqui e depois apagou. Muito estranho, mas consegui copiar o código a tempo rsrsr. Basta trocar a primeira linha por `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caro Italo, eu não sei se tem haver, mas o próprio Wordpress adiciona isto:

Linha 103:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://drglass.com.br/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

e na linha 381 você adicionou isto:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Pode ser a causa do conflito, realmente recomendo que remova o segundo jQuery, mesmo que não tenha relação com o problema, isso não esta certo.

Eu não consegui testar ou analisar mais coisas, eram muitos `.js` para olhar, mas já lhe adianto, se não for o primeiro problema citado, algo deve estar impedindo ou sobrescrevendo a variável global `$`, note que se usar `jQuery` funciona normalmente, provavelmente é alguma lib ou add-on, ou é proprio do wordpress que esteja usando [`jQuery.noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

O que você pode fazer é isolar o escopo fazendo isto:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#uf").on("change", function () {
        atualizaProfissional();
    });

    $("#botao").on("click", function(){
        s = $("#municipio").val();
        if (s == 1){
            $("#imagem").attr("src","https://drglass.com.br/uf/popup1.png");
            $("#mensagem").html('Uhul! Nós atendemos sua região. Temos uma unidade de atendimento pertinho de você. Ligue agora mesmo e faça um orçamento.');
        }else{
            $("#imagem").attr("src","https://drglass.com.br/uf/popup0.png");
            $("#mensagem").html('Ops! Ainda não estamos na sua cidade. Mas muito em breve levaremos a melhor empresa de Vidros para sua região, consulte nosso plano de expansão.');
        }
    });

    function atualizaProfissional() {
        var options = {};
        options.url = "https://drglass.com.br/uf/listaCidades.php";
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = { "uf": $("#uf").val() };
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.success = function (data) {
            $('#municipio').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#municipio").append("<option value='" + data[i].atende + "'>" + data[i].Nome + "</option>");
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Ou simplesmente adaptar tudo para `jQuery()...`